# Angular directive and css class with same name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a situation where angular directive and css class has same name. For example

```
<div class="abc" > ... </div>
```

I this scenario "abc" is interpreted as angular directive. How can I make angular to ignore "abc" in this particular case.

Note: I can't change name of css class nor directive.

Edit:

Few more details: Here both angular directive and css class are from third party and I should not make changes in them. So is there any way without changing directive code or class name?

Comment: The answers about directive restrictive are good but maybe you should think about namespace since you clearly have an issue here ;) Cheers

Comment: This. A thousand times this. Use a sensible namespace for your directives, there's a good reason it's `ng-click` and not `click`. Pick a prefix for your directves (and make sure it's not `ng-`).

Comment: I think what you really want -not chaging the css nor the directive- is not possible. You should go for one of the many options already mentioned.

Comment: @Martijn : That's what I wanted to know. Whether is there some sort of escape character which says don't consider this class as directive. Some thing like class="@abc" or ng-class="abc".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default angular directives only apply to attributes.

If your directive already has a property of `{ restrict: "C" }` just remove it.

From [angular $compile docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile):

> #### restrict
>
> String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific
>   directive declaration style. If omitted, the default (**attributes only**)
>   is used.
>
> - E - Element name:
> - A - Attribute
>     (default):
> - C - Class:
> - M - Comment:

#### Create a terminal directive

If you cannot change the name of css class nor directive maybe you can create a terminal directive with a higher priority on the same element.

```
.directive('stop', function() {
  return {
    priority: 2000,
    terminal: true
  }
});
```

Markup:

```
<div stop class="abc" > ... </div>
```

This would not work if there are any child element directives that needs to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs...

```
.directive('abc', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A'
    };
});
```